# why is my app crashing while I am jus switching an activity?

Tags: android

I am using intent to just switch activities but my app crashes when i call main activity ... why is it so?code is as follows

```
public void activitymain(View view){
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: What is your current activity name ?

Comment: show us the error message

Comment: What will you do with view by the way ?

Comment: share error log

Comment: Check MainActivity declare  in manifest file

Comment: have you put android:onClick="activitymain" in the button when you click on?

Comment: @ste9206 : yes it was a response to a button

Comment: @user2025187 : i did not mention there before , i tried it now , it works (y) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public void activitymain(){
        Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this ,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: hey if i don't mention view in it , it actually shows an error log , which says no view mentioned.... so i guess it is necessary to mention view in arg.

Comment: I can't see from where you called this method. So I removed it. If this is working with view then I'll add this to my question.

Comment: Btw, why did you changed the accepted answer ? may I know ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
public void switchActivity(){
    Intent i=new Intent(FirstActivityName.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```